# Google Compute duplicate a instance with multiple disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to duplicate running Google Compute Instance which has multiple disk attached to it to a new instance?  Such as all the data present in Source instance (both Bootdisk and Additional Disk) are present in the newly duplicated instance also.

As the Image creation in GCE is based on Source single disk selection, is it possible to copy all the additional disk also?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve desired instance, first create snapshot(s) of the disk(s) instance you want to "duplicate", as described in [Creating persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)

Use boot disk snapshot created above to create a new instance, as described in [Creating an instance from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot)

Attach additional disk(s) accordingly to new create instance, as described in [Adding a zonal persistent disk to your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a [machine image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images) for a running GCE instance with multiple disks from the GCP console. To perform that, enter into the VM details UI and click "Create Machine Image" button in the above.

Next, you need to create a VM from that image. From the Compute Engine panel to the left, go to Machine Images tab, click your target machine image. You will find "[Create Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-instance-from-machine-image)" button to fulfill your wish.

This will have all data present in Source instance (both Bootdisk and Additional Disk) in the newly duplicated instance also.